# Open a Visual Studio Solution with a Visual Studio Add-in

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, add-in

I have a Visual Studio Add-in, and I want to open a solution. How can I open the solution in the currently running instance of Visual Studio. Any tips? My Add-in is written in VB.NET.

So far I have `myStreamWriter.WriteLine("start mySolution.sln /D .")` which writes to the command prompt. This opens the solution in Visual Studio 2012, however, it opens in a new instance of Visual Studio rather than in the instance that is already running. Any tips?

Comment: So far I have "myStreamWriter.WriteLine("start mySolution.sln /D .")" which writes to the command prompt. This opens the solution in Visual Studio 2012, however, it opens in a new instance of Visual 
Studio rather than in the instance that is already running. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `ExecuteCommand` to execute the standard `File.OpenProject` command. Similar to using the <kbd>File</kbd>><kbd>Open</kbd>><kbd>Solution</kbd>.

Something like this will do in C#:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyAddin1\MyAddin1.sln";
path = "\"" + path + "\"";
_applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenProject", path);
```

Which translates to VB.NET:

```
Dim path As String
path = """C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyAddin1\MyAddin1.sln"""
DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenProject", path)
```

If you would like to know whether the command has finished, you should create an eventhandler for the command.

Comment: This does in fact open the solution but it doesn't get listed in the File|Recent Projects and Solutions... Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I can only guess but it might be because File.OpenProject is used as a subsequent operation when you open a solutions in VS and there are other adjoining operations running beside when you do it from a menu command, or VS using another command from a menu or from Start Page.